# Why does my Honda Fit Sport overheat?

Tags: honda, cooling-system, overheating

I have a 2007 Honda Fit Sport. The car has been overheating. I have taken it to all the good mechanics, yet the problem persists. When on a highway at speed up to 100 (kph?), the car starts to overheat. I have replaced the radiator, but the problem continues.

Comment: Does this only happen at highway speeds?

Answer (score 1):

check the radiator cap..thermostat partially worn,possible brakes not fully releasing.check your temperature gauge sensor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has a few possible causes.

First, the temperature sensor may be defective, this sensor triggers the fan to turn on. When you’re only activating the fan with the aircon relay, when your cabin cools, the compressor turns off, the aircon turns off as well. With a defective coolant sensor, you will overheat.

Second, the thermostat valve may be stuck up. Change. Check all your fan fuse and relay. The fan relays located below the battery. The fuse is under the dashboard beside the steering wheel.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the cooling fan/s and waterpump... And relevant relays and fuses. Sounds like either (or both) are not spinning fast enough. Also check your coolant level.

Comment: How could the waterpump be spinning not fast enough, as it has a direct correspondence to engine speed? It's spinning either fast enough or not at all (broken belt). Cooling fans are not needed at highway speeds.

Comment: I agree; I'm not an automotive mechanic, just an amateur with a healthy amount of understanding of how mechanical things work, including an M.Sc. degree in engineering / technology. The largest mechanical thing I have done is to build a bicycle from the scratch. Despite not being a professional mechanic, I have managed to obtain quite a lot of reputation points here. I am happy to be corrected by others; it seems you are not.